# Remove First and last row of csv file with batch script

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to remove the first and the last row of CSV files in a folder and after that merge them to make one csv file.

I am trying to remove the first and last row with the batch script below but its not working:

```
@echo on 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.csv) do (
find /v "RemoveThis" < %%a >> %%~Na.csv
)
```

Anyone has done similar batch script before. Can someone help me with this one.

The CSV will look like this.

```
0   RemoveThis                                  
1   6105829 4   541746546   46542114546 56541651651 132 132 1   31/12/2017 20:43    31/12/2017 20:45
1   6105837 4   4545    6546    4465465 396 396 1   31/12/2017 18:20    31/12/2017 18:26
1   6105844 4   21656565    46546546    4654466546  36  36  1   31/12/2017 19:27    31/12/2017 19:27
1   6105845 4   45454   45454   465465  2   2   1   31/12/2017 19:26    31/12/2017 19:26
99  RemoveThis      188
```

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell you could do it using the `Get-Content` cmdlet to retrieve the text, skip the first and last line using the `Select-Object` cmdlet and finally append it to the merge file using the `Add-Content` cmdlet.

To iterate over each csv use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Filter '*.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_ | Select -Skip 1 | Select -SkipLast 1 | Add-Content d:\merge.csv
}
```

Comment: Im sure it can but I am not familiar with it. You added the PowerShell tag so I provided you a solution with PowerShell..

Comment: That answer will remove the header from a csv file rather than the first row.

Comment: @Dave Thats true but based on his example this is what he needs.

Comment: Absolutely! I didn't mean it as a critic of your answer, rather an additional note. I have added a solution that keeps the header.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer which keeps the column headers.

```
#Set source Directory
$SourcePath = "D:\CsvFiles"

#Create new subdirectory 
$SubDir = New-Item -Path $SourcePath -Name NewCsv -ItemType Directory

# Get all files with csv extension
$CsvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -filter "*.csv"

#Loop through files
foreach ($File in $CsvFiles)
{
   #Import the csv file
   $Csv = Import-Csv -Path $File.FullName

   #Create Destination Path for new csv file based on file name
   $Des = Join-Path -Path $SubDir.FullName -ChildPath $File.Name

   #remove first and last row from csv but keep column header
   $NewCsv = $Csv | where {$_ -ne $Csv[-1] -and $_ -ne $Csv[0]}

   #Save to new file
   $NewCsv | Export-Csv -Path $Des
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is not a column header record, the following will do what you are asking.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -ReadCount 1
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Select-Object -SkipLast 1
    }
```